# Add encryption to travis notifications in slack channel

Tags: encryption, github, slack

I have the following issue:

For now I have successfully added travis notifications to slack channel by editing the travis.yml file. My next step is adding data encryption. I've gone through the slack manual about travis and found that I have to add something the following line of code:

```
language: bash
travis encrypt "account:token#channel_name" --add notifications.slack
notifications:
  slack: account:token#channel_name
```

Without the second line of code the travis worked perfectly and notifications were send to the channel but after I've added the line of code supposed to do the encryption, travis failed with the following output:

**The error was "could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 2 column 1".**

I've also tried to add

```
.rooms
```

after

```
notifications.slack
```

or to remove the channel name from the line supposed to do the encryption but without any success. I've added **:** before **travis encrypt** but still have the same error!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is looking for an answer. You need to run that command with the [Travis CLI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb). Install it and run `travis encrypt "account:token#channel_name" --add notifications.slack` in the folder of the repository you want to add the slack integration.